# sbt: Running specific main method from the command line

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

I have several methods annotated with `@main` and it totally beats me how to run one of them specifically from a terminal, even after thoroughly looking at the sbt documentation. All I can find is how to specify what source file my main class is in. My project contains only one file though, so this is not really helpful.

Assume I have the following (where root being the project's root directory of course):

```
├── root
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── scala
│               └── main.scala
```

and `main.scala` looks something like this:

```scala
object main:
  @main def foo(): Unit = ???
  @main def bar(): Unit = ???
```

Is the only way to run either `foo` or `bar` from a shell to distribute up my methods over several files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run either methods from inside SBT shell via:

```
runMain foo
```

or

```
runMain bar
```

Comment: You're close! I had already tried that, but apparently never with the right set of quotationmarks, capitalizations etc: `sbt "runMain foo"` did the trick.

Comment: @Aarkon you are doing it from outside SBT shell and passing commands that needs to be executed inside SBT shell as a string parameter. check this:
 https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Running-Commands.html#Provide+multiple+commands+to+run+consecutively